# query_post Pagination

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having a hell of a time trying to display pagination on a homepage. I am calling two query_posts resetting both at the end of their loop. I have home.php setup like this.

```
           <div id="featured">

                <!-- Start Featured Loop -->
                <?php query_posts("posts_per_page=2&tag=featured"); ?>
        <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    //some loop stuff                        

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?><!-- End Featured Loop -->

            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
      </div> <!-- End Featured -->


      <div id="home-grid">

    <?php 
            if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); }
            elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); }
            else { $paged = 1; }

            query_posts('posts_per_page=3&paged=' . $paged); 
            ?>
         <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

             <?php while(have_posts()); ?>

        // some loop stuff


               <?php endwhile; else: ?>
               <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
               <?php endif; ?>

            <div class="home-pagi">
        <?php next_posts_link(); ?>
                <?php previous_posts_link(); ?>
            </div>

               <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I can get the "next page" link to display but when clicked I get 404 error. I have tried every fix in the codex but can not seem to get this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop at the bottom seems to be missing the `while` and `endwhile` parts that make it a loop.

Please try the pagination after the `endwhile`.

Here's a link to the [Codex Pagination Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Adding_the_.22paged.22_parameter_to_a_query)

Comment: I am sorry for forgetting to add them to my post. They are in my home.php I just forgot to include them into the post.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to this:

```
global $wp_query;
query_posts(
    array_merge(
        array(
        'category__not_in' => 69,
        'tag' => 'featured'
         ),
        $wp_query->query
    )
);
```